# How do I remove backslashes from records in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Long story short, I have backslashes in my data due to PHP magic quotes. I have straightened out what was wrong there, but have some records now which have unnecessary backslashes.

```
1 | This is an example of \' single, \" double, and \\ backslash (in the messed up records)
2 | This example is how it gets stored now \ backslash ' single " double
```

When I want to output my data, I need to use strip slashes to fix the issue and get the following output:

```
1 | This is an example of ' single, " double, and \ backslash
```

But then this one is wrong:

```
2 | This example is how it gets stored now backslash ' single " double
```

Thus stripslashes in my php is removing a slash which isn't technically used to escape anything.

I want to not have to use strip slashes, since my data should be clean like this:

```
1 | This is an example of ' single, " double, and \ backslash (how data should be)
```

How can I query to replace `\'` and `\"` and `\\` with `'` `"` and `\`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmpTable;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmpTable ( BadText VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO tmpTable
SELECT 'This is an example of \\\' single, \\\"double, and \\\\ backslash';

select BadText from tmpTable;

update tmpTable
set BadText = replace(replace(replace(BadText,'\\\'','\''),'\\\"','"'),'\\\\','\\');

select BadText as GoodText from tmpTable;
```

Comment: tried this out on a few fields in my development environment, seems to be doing exactly what I need, removing escaping backslashes, but leaving intact actual backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

A `REGEX_REPLACE` would be the easiest for this since you can remove more than one slash and replace it with nothing. Unfortunately, there is no such thing in MySQL but there is a nice [UDF for RegExReplace on Launchpad](https://code.launchpad.net/~vcs-imports/mysql-udf-regexp/trunk) (need to compile it yourself but that shouldn't be a problem IMO).

So with the UDF installed, something like

```
SELECT REGEX_REPLACE(your_column, '.*backslash{2,}.*', 'backslash') FROM table
```

Haven't tested it but it should work. It uses the same REGEX as [already supported](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using PHP, you can use the stripslashes() function. They work with magic quotes too. [Click here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) to see the PHP doc.

Comment: http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=19947 and http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=27848. 
As I stated in my question, I can't simply use stripslashes, I want to actually clean up my data.

Answer (score 0):

The question is how to you stop getting them.
use JSON_MERGE(YOUR_JSON_STRING, JSON_OBJECT()) any time you do anything with a JSON variable.