# Using SESSION sql_mode = 'NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES' before running query to remove backslashes in database

Tags: mysql

See this post:

[How do I remove backslashes from records in MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2261/how-do-i-remove-backslashes-from-records-in-mysql)

I have similar issues in that code that was developed before me did not use strip slashes with magic_quotes_gpc on before inserting it into a database. Now I want to remove a walk_array ('stripslashes'... call to gain some performance and prevent the stripslashes function from being run on every select instead of every insert or update (which happens much less).

Now my question is:

Is it not neccesary to use:

> SET SESSION sql_mode = 'NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES';

Before I run a query like this:

```
update tbl_closet set inlognaam=replace(replace(replace(replace(inlognaam,"\\\'","\'"),'\\\"','"'),'\\\\','\\'),'\\&','&');
```

Beacuse if I do not then the query will also use backslash as escape and things go wrong??

Comment: Test it with a simple test case?

Comment: i did and the result i expected (for example four slashes \\\\ replace by two \\) are achieved when running the set session sql mode='no_backslash_escapes', but i wanted to make sure that i did not overlook the intention of the other post's solution...

Comment: In my opinion, `magic_quotes_gpc` is more trouble than benefit.